# Held needed with a slightly complex htaccess workaround for multisite!

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to build a multisite structure.

I have got a directory structure like the following :
where home contains the main code and other folder contains files relative to each site

```
/home
/home/...[allthefilesandcontent]

/folder1
/folder1/..[someoptionalfilesandcontent]


/folder2
/folder2/..[someoptionalfilesandcontent]
```

I want that if I access /folder1/folder_or_file_do_not_exist.ext
it should map to the relative path to home 
i.e. /home/folder_or_file_would_exist.ext

And if I access `/folder1/folder_or_file_exists.ext`
it should remain the same.

We can use mod rewrite or may be I am wrong .. Is there anyway we can do it through `ErrorDocument` thing!

Comment: 1) You have to find out if you can use `mod_rewrite` or not (as I do not see how it can be done without it) 2) What is the root folder (if someone requests `domain.com/`, will it go to `/` folder ... or maybe `/home`)? 3) those `/folder1/`, `/folder2/` are they fixed number and they known in advance ?

Comment: Yes I can use mod_rewrite and I have been using it for other usual rewrite practices! but i am stuck at this multisite thing!

/folder1 etc can be anything. 

At the root i have an index file that redirects it to /home

I believe it has something to do with 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d or something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job on test environment ... but requires testing on your setup + in may depend on your existing rewrite rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/home/$2 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/home/$2 -d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /home/$2 [L]
```

Test URL: `/meow/123.txt`

- Assuming this file DOES exist -- in this case the rule above will not kick in (as expected).
- If file does not exist, but `/home/123.txt` does, then `/home/123.txt` will be used instead.
- If there is no such file in BOTH folders `/home/123.txt` & `/meow/123.txt` then nothing happens (rule is not getting triggered and the rest depends what other rules/instructions you have in your .htaccess).

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't get this setup working on my setup hosted on 1and1. Anyways I have made some other workarounds to get my work done! 
Any ways I am accepting your answers! Might be that 1and1 has some awkward setup!

Comment: @user546305 Do you mind sharing your final config -- so I can see for my own references/for the future (in case I will run into similar problems one day). Thnx

Comment: I actually setup an index file along with an htaccess in each folder when they are created.